# how to gunzip multiple files at once to a specific folder?

Tags: linux, command

I have a folder `/mydata` that contains several `gz` files.

I would like to unzip all of them (while keeping the original zips) to another folder `/myoutput`

How can I do that? Can I keep track of the unzipping process as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `gzip`, `basename`, and a loop:

```
for pathname in /mydata/*.gz; do
    gzip -dc "$pathname" >"/myoutput/$( basename "$pathname" .gz )"
done
```

This will iterate over all pathnames that matches `/mydata/*.gz`, and for each such name, it will use `gzip` to decompress (`-d`) the file to standard output (`-c`).  The output is redirected to a file in `/myoutput`. The filename will be the same as for the original file, but without the `.gz` filename suffix (`basename` is used to remove this bit from the pathname, as well as to remove the initial `/mydata/` string).

The command inside the loop could also be written as

```
gzip -d -o "/myoutput/$( basename "$pathname" .gz )" "$pathname"
```

which would let `gzip` write to the output file directly instead of via a redirection.

This assumes that the file under `/mydata` are readable, and that you have permission to create files in `/myoutput`.

Comment: would that keep the original file as well? is gunzip the same thing as gzip -dc? thanks!

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ This would only _read_ from the original files, not change them in any way. `gunzip` is more or less a wrapper around `gzip -d`, you could use `gunzip -c` here in place of `gzip -dc`.

Comment: `pv "$pathname" | zcat > myoutput/\`basename "$pathname" .gz\`` will give you a progress bar for each file. It's useful for large files.

Answer (score 1):

- If you really want to the target directory directly under the root, give it suitable ownership (and permissions)

  ```
  sudo mkdir /myoutput
  sudo chown $USER /myoutput
  ```
- Change directory to your directory, that contains the `gz` files.

  ```
  cd /mydata
  ```
- Run the following command line

  ```
  for i in *.gz;do echo -n "${i/.gz}|";zcat "$i" > "/myoutput/${i/.gz}";done; echo ""
  ```

Comment: thanks! pretty nice. I do not understand the part `${i/.gz}`. I assume `i` is the full path of my file (as a string), correct?

Comment: `i` is the file name (for each file in turn). ${i/.gz} will remove `.gz` from the whole name string (if found in the string). This is described in `man bash`: " ${parameter/pattern/string} Pattern substitution. The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in  pathname expansion ... If string is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the / following pattern may be omitted."